# Client-Server command pattern

Tags: java, command, client-server

I'm making a client-server application based on the command pattern. But I don't understand how best to do it. Who should store the command implementation, the client or the server? That is, the server knows nothing about commands, and the client sends to the server a command object that the server must execute, or the client doesn't know the implementation and sends only the name of the command?

Client-Server with command pattern